# Store a selector in a variable Javascript and then use a method on it

Tags: javascript, variables, methods

I have check some others post, and document myself but I dont know what is the problem here.

I have 2 image (would like to have like 20 at the end) where you can click on an icon and show and hide and image in the webpage. If you click on image A it should show image A, if you click on image B image A should hide and image B should be sown.

```
var firsttime = 1;
var $lastletter;
$(function() {
    $('#A').click(function() {
        if (firsttime = 0){
            $lastletter.toggle();
            $('#AL').toggle();
            $lastletter  = $( '#AL' );
        }
        else
        {
            firsttime = 0;
            $('#AL').toggle();
            $lastletter  = $( '#AL' );
        }
    });
});
$(function() {
    $('#B').click(function() {
        if (firsttime = 0){
            $lastletter.toggle();
            $('#BL').toggle();
            $lastletter  = $( '#BL' );
        }
        else
        {
            firsttime = 0;
            $('#BL').toggle();
            $lastletter  = $( '#BL' );
        }
    });
});
```

This is the solution im using:

```
$(function() {
    $('.imgLetter').click(function() {
        if (lastletter != this.id) {
            $('#' + lastletter + 'L').toggle();
            lastletter=this.id;
        }
        $('#' + this.id + 'L').toggle();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're conventionally assigning the "last letter" by appending an "L" to the ID: this could get a lot simpler. Decorate all of your `#<x>` elements with a class name that makes it easy to select all of them at once. I'm going to choose "letter".

I don't think you even need to track the "first time". It sounds like you just want one element to toggle another. That would look like:

```
$(function() {
    $('.letter').click(function() {
        $('#' + this.id + 'L').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me, this was the final solution im using right now.